# Do we need to take care of any image dimensions to support iPad mini?

Tags: ios, ipad

Hi is their any extra things like image dimensions or any kinda plist property set up or any kinda extra set up we need to take care for my iPad app so as to support iPad mini

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. You just should have each image in two versions, non-retina and retina resolution (the @2x thing). But you should have done that anyway to support retina.

iPad mini uses a non-retina resolution. From an UI perspective, you can compare it to iPad (1) and iPad 2.

Comment: Note that the next iPad mini might be retina as well.

Comment: Well, who cares? The point is its absolut resolution in terms of pixels in x and y, not the density of points in dpi on the screen. So physically it may be retina. From an app developer's point of view it behaves like any pre-retina iPad.